# How to implement cascading dropdowns using results from an HTTP POST request on backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone-routing, netsuite

There is an address view which renders a form with the basic address fields including zip code textbox and city/suburb dropdown. Ideally when the user types in the the zip code, the city dropdown should automatically populate with values (cities/suburbs) under that zip code. I know someone already raised a question about cascading dropdowns however this is different in a way that I want the values of the cities/suburbs should be taken as a result by calling an HTTP Get request.

How do I implement it using backbone.js? I have done something but i feel that it is somehow wrong. What I did is I added a function that will populate a "suburbs" collection and return the collection as a parameter in calling a macro that will update the dropdown. Codes below.

code snippets from Address.Model.js

```
...

 , updateCities:function(){

        var suburb = Backbone.Model.extend({
        });

        var SuburbCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
          model: suburb,
          url:"http link to get the suburbs list"
        });

        var SubCol = new SuburbCollection();

        SubCol.fetch();
        return SubCol;
} 
...
```

Code snippets from citiesDropdown macro

```
<% registerMacro('citiesDropdown', function (options) { %>
<%
    var suburbs= options.cities;

%>
    <label class="control-label" for="<%= options.manage ? options.manage : ''%>state">
        <%= _('City').translate() %>
        <small><%= _('(required)').translate() %></small>
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select class="input-xlarge" id="<%= options.manage ? options.manage : ''%>city" name="city" data-type="city">
            <option value="">
                <%= _('-- Select --').translate() %>
            </option>
            <% _.each(suburbs, function (suburb) { %>
            <option>
                <%= suburb.name %>
            </option>
            <% }) %>
        </select>
    </div>

<% }) %>
```

Address.View

```
...
, events: {
...
   ,'blur input[data-type="zip"]': 'updateCity'
...


, updateCity: function (e)
    {
        this.$('[data-type="city"]').closest('.control-group').empty().append(
            SC.macros.citiesDropdown({
                cities: this.model.updateCities()
            })
        );
    }
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something very similar for countries and their regions.

If that can help you i have extract my code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nboncoure/7fd0e00b2d04f40a4434).

The select inputs are decorated with [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) but it should be easy to removing if you doesn't want it.